# How to extract datetime of a location when it was added to the google maps?

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to extract datetime of a location pin when it was added in Google maps.
For e.g. if I search McDonalds in an area then it should give datetime for all McDonald locations in that area with their datetime.
Is there a way to pull up that data.

P.S. This question may not belong here so apologies for that. I have tried other forums but I couldn't find any relevant information.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you are using google maps API for development, so if you want to get place details then you can use Place API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service

Nearby Search and Text Search allow additional parameters to filter results, (e.g. minprice, maxprice, opennow, and type).

PlaceOpeningHours is parameter from which you can get time for particular place

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place#PlaceOpeningHours

I hope this answer is helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am looking for the time when a place pin was added to the maps not the opening time for that place.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).